# Module build failed Angular

Tags: angular

Hello Thank you for your contribution

i have this error in Angular app after i updated it to Angular 9

ERROR in ./src/app/error/error.module.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /Users/kadrihasimi32/Desktop/desktop/academy/academy-client/src/app/error/error.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
         "module": "es2015",
        "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"

  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

```
 tsconfig.json
```

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a lazy loaded module? Try to check the difference between Angular 8 and 9 in lazy loaded modules and app.routing... I had something similar some days ago and the problem was there.

Comment: zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24496)
    at core.js:24507
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24507)
    at core.js:24507
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24507)
    at core.js:24507
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24507)

Comment: Can you post your `routing.module` or routes config?

Comment: @NorbertBartko: You're right. I had similar issue and fixed it updating the routing.module